# Timer switch android TimerTask

Tags: android, timer, timertask

```
b= new TimerTask()
{
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        out_string = hi.getWebPage("http://daniandroid.honor.es/getAllCustomers.php"); 
        frum_timer = Integer.parseInt(out_string.replaceAll("[\\D]",""));
    };
}; 
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(b, 500, 1000);
```

Every **1000 ms**, run() will store the value to int **frum_timer**

I'm using this for an flashlight application.
When I open the app, I want my app to switch on and off flashlights using frum_timer for *interval time*.

So if

```
frum_timer = 1000;
```

my flashlight will turn on and off every 1 sec. 
and if I edit to

```
frum_timer = 300;
```

it will turn on and off every 0.3 sec.

I tried instantiate a **new TimerTask()**

```
c=new TimerTask()
{
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        timetask = new TimerTask() 
        {
            boolean checking = false;
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        if(checking==true)
                        {
                            //camera turning on
                            checking=false; 
                        }else{
                            //camera turninf off
                            checking=true;  
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }
};
//some code
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(c, 50, 700);
```

but it's quite hard, because when I change the value, a new timer will start and the old one will **remain active.**

*BTW: I know that the code for turning on/off will not change at the same interval as I want because of my amateur programmer skills (if checking...etc)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way.

```
 new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start();
```